# How to retrieve holdings by address by token?

Tags: tokens, erc-20, addresses, etherscan, explorers

One can find on etherscan, for any token, [the list of holdings by address](https://etherscan.io/token/ZRX#balances).

I would like to retrieve this info programmatically. Does the etherscan API enable us to do this?

If not, what is a good way of getting this info?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this with the API is to look for the logs of the token contract (transfer for instance), then you will know who has been using the token. After that, you can just call the method "balanceof" to get the balances of the addresses that you found.

Hope this helps